# Windows analogue of Linux nm to see contents of PYD files?

Tags: python, pyd

I'd like to see what classes and functions are present in a PYD I have. Are there tools for Windows that let me do that, comparable to how `nm` on Linux lets me see the symbols defined in .so files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will allow you to examine the symbols and linkage of any DLL.

Comment: Huh, should've thought of tools for inspecting DLLs - thanks, I'll give that a try!